# Python/Pandas : How to self join a pandas dataframe on rows with same index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like below

| merge_id | identifier | Location | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | DEL | 50 |
| 1 | B2 | HYD | 60 |
| 2 | C1 | BEN | 80 |
| 2 | D2 | HYD | 10 |

I want the output dataframe to look like below

| merge_id | identifier | Location | Value | m_identifier | m_Location | m_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | DEL | 50 | B2 | HYD | 60 |
| 2 | C1 | BEN | 80 | D2 | HYD | 10 |

Please can you suggest how I can do that

Comment: Can you double check your output? Also what would happen with more rows per id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with a few tweaks:

```
df2 = (df.assign(c=df.groupby('merge_id').cumcount())
         .pivot(index='merge_id', columns='c')
         .sort_index(level=1, sort_remaining=False, axis=1)
      )

df2.columns = df2.columns.map(lambda x: f'{"m_" if x[1] else ""}{x[0]}')

print(df2.reset_index())
```

output:

```
   merge_id identifier Location  Value m_identifier m_Location  m_Value
0         1         A1      DEL     50           B2        HYD       60
1         2         C1      BEN     80           D2        HYD       10
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way about it

```
df2=df.merge(df.mask(df['identifier'].str.endswith('1')),
         on='merge_id',
          how='left',
        suffixes=(None,'_m'))
df2=df2.mask(df2['identifier'].eq(df2['identifier_m']))
df2.dropna()
```

```
    merge_id    identifier  Location    Value   identifier_m    Location_m  Value_m
0        1.0            A1       DEL     50.0             B2           HYD     60.0
2        2.0            C1       BEN     80.0             D2           HYD     10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
grouped = df.groupby('merge_id')
df1 = df.loc[grouped.head(1).index]
df2 = df.loc[grouped.tail(1).index].add_prefix('m_')
out = (df1.merge(df2, left_on='merge_id', right_on='m_merge_id')
       .drop('m_merge_id', axis = 1))
```

Output:

```
   merge_id identifier Location  Value m_identifier m_Location  m_Value
0         1         A1      DEL     50           B2        HYD       60
1         2         C1      BEN     80           D2        HYD       10
```